in VBA objXML.loadXML(strXML) thows error "DTD/schema not valid"
I think the answer of the endpoint is not fully loaded by objXML.loadXML, so there is an error "problem with DTD"
I try to read an api. it works fine with postman, header and XML looks ok
But if I try to call this endpoint with VBA (with ms-access 2016) like this, there are problems
  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  
  XMLRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
  XMLRequest.send "apiKey=" & apiKey
  
  Dim x
  x = XMLRequest.responseXML.XML
  debug.print x
  If Not objXML.loadXML(XMLRequest.responseXML.XML) Then
    Debug.Print objXML.parseError.reason
  End If


i see the start of the xml file when hoovering over x "...
debug.print x show a part of the file only: the end
and objXML.loadXML fails with parseError.reason like "problems with DTD" and names two fields

I don't think that the xml is corrupt. I don't find a problem with the mentioned fields. I think it may be because the xml is not loaded fully like "x" is not shown fully. So then not all infos of the DTD could be found.
Does anyone has any idea what goes wrong here ?
BTW: I get the same error if I save the postman output as an xml-file and try to load it via objXML.load(filename)

halfly solved: it really seems to be a problem with the DTD/schema inside the XML. If i delete the schema in the file and import it via MS-Access UI or VBA code: both works.
completely solved:
with additional line
objXML.validateOnParse = False
you can advise the code to ignore the DTD/scheme :-)

I'd reserve the "completely solved" label for actually having resolved the problem with your DTD or schema, which would have been ideal to have included in your question.
